# How to format asp.net mvc Razor code in vs2015?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2015, format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3kkx.png)

I install vs 2015 and open my project . when I save all cshtml file ,the server code format change. How can I format the file.